# Windows hook stopped working when program is reading database in qt?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, ms-access, setwindowshookex

My program has a bug which has struggled me for days. My program set windows hook to listen to keyboard press and mouse click, whenever a key is being pressed or the mouse is being clicked, the relevant variable will add one number. And when the program starts, those variables will be initiated to some values which are read from database. Basically the bug occurs if I keep pressing keyboard or mouse when the program starts, then the windows hook will just stop working. And I tried my best to solve this bug, and I wrote many minimal examples as small as I can, but there bug is still here. I will just show what my code looks like in the most minimal example: 
In the `widget.cpp:`
I set the hook like:

```
HHOOK hHook = NULL;

LRESULT CALLBACK MyLowLevelKeyBoardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (wParam == WM_KEYUP) {
        Emitter::Instance()->keyPressed(); //emit this signal whenever a key is being pressed
        qDebug() << "Key Pressed"; //when hook stopped working, the debug message will not even show
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(hHook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

and in `widget`'s constructor:

```
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    hHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, MyLowLevelKeyBoardProc, NULL, 0);  //set hook here

    pressedTimes = database.returnTotalPressedTimes(); //get data from database and initiate pressedTimes
    ui->label->setText(QString::number(pressedTimes));

    connect(Emitter::Instance(), &SignalEmitter::keyPressed, [this](){ pressedTimes++; ui->label->setText(QString::number(pressedTimes)); }); //when key presses, ++pressedTimes;
}
```

And the `Database class` is like:

```
Database::Database()
{
    QString dbName = QString("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)}; FIL={MS Access}; DBQ= C:/path/to/TestingDB.mdb");
    database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QODBC");
    database.setDatabaseName(dbName);
}

//this function is used to initiate the pressedTimes variable when the program starts
int Database::returnTotalPressedTimes()
{
    int totalPressedTimes = 0;

    if(database.open()) {
        QSqlQuery sqlQuery;
        sqlQuery.exec("SELECT SUM(PressedTimes) FROM TestingTable"); //I trid my best to the testing database as simple as possible
        while(sqlQuery.next()) {
            totalPressedTimes = sqlQuery.value(0).toInt();
        }
        database.close();
    }
    else {
        qDebug() << database.lastError().text();
    }

    return totalPressedTimes;
}
```

So as you can see, basically I showed all the code of the minimal example. So when the program starts, it reads data from database and initiate the data to `pressedTimes`, and `pressedTimes` will add one number each time when a key is being pressed. 
But the bug just occurs the moment you start your program, and in the mean time, you keep pressing the keyboard. Then the hook just stopped working. Do not know what is really going on there and how to solve this weird bug. Hope I explain my question clearly and hope someone can help me solve this bug. 
Thanks.  
**Edit:**
BTW, I forgot to say, as far as I tested it, if I just initiate `pessedTimes` to 0 or just some other values instead of getting value from reading database. The bug will not happen. So does that mean there are some conflicts between windows hook and reading database? 
And I am using windows 10 and the database is windows access.

Comment: @user202729 ok, I edited my question.

Comment: This looks like an example of an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). If I understand your intentions correctly, you actually want your program to read data line-by-line from a database and then update the GUI whenever the user presses a key. Am I right?

Comment: @RobbieE Yes, you are right. When the program starts, it will read data from database and initiate the data to a variable, and when user presses a key, the variable will be updated. And The bug occurs if I keep pressing the key when the program starts.